# "Rotate image" vs. "spin image"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

I need to title an application button that moves an image 90 degrees clockwise/anticlockwise.

Which of the following fits better?

> - Spin image
> - Rotate image

Comment: If possible, I'd use an icon that shows the meaning, avoiding language ambiguity.

Comment: In these technical terms, we don't have much choice but to follow standards and conventions, or the user will not  understand us correctly.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes, there are icons for both 'Rotate CW' and 'Rotate CCW'.

Comment: There is no one right answer, So I don't think this is a constructive question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Rotate".

That is the correct and standard word.

Rotate can be used for a turn that is less than, equal to or more than 360°. Spin usually implies more than one full turn around -- even many turns at high speed.

Comment: To me, "Spin" also has a connotation that is perhaps best expressed in physics terms as "impart angular momentum", i.e. when you let go of the object, it keeps moving around its axis.  So for example you spin a wheel to see where it stops (due to friction), but you rotate a wheel to position one of its spokes pointing northward.

Comment: Nice to be of help, @Tom. Welcome to ELU!

Comment: @Hellion Yes, that's true. Think 'spin' bowling in cricket.

Answer (score 3):

***Spin*** [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spin) to rotate quickly, implying that it will rotate through more than 90 degrees.  I'd say "rotate".